# Tix Tutorials in Python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tix

I recently have become interested in GUI programming in Python.

I have already had plenty of experience with Pygame, but find that it would be easier just to use the interface that Tkinter, Tix, etc... provide.

However, I'm having difficulty finding any decent documentation or tutorials on **Tix for Python**. (Unlike Pygame, which there are several guides/tutorials that I find quite nice)

Where can I find a nice tutorial? (That only assumes knowledge of Python, and hopefully no knowledge of Tk)

Answer (score 4):

[*Tix*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.tix.html) is a set of additional widgets that weren't originally included in the standard *Tkinter* distribution. Now that the improved [*ttk*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) toolkit is part of *Tkinter* in newer Python versions (2.7 or 3.2), *Tix* is no longer necessary. More discussion can be found [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t651741-state-of-the-art-tkinter-tk-8-5-tix.html).

A good tutorial on modern Tk can be found [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/).

Comment: I'm curious by your comment *Tix is no longer necessary*. Tix seems to still have functionality that Tkinter and ttk don't. For example, Tix has the only `checklist` for Python that I know about. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some additional searching, I found the answer to my own question (finally!)

[Thinking in Tkinter by Stephen Ferg](http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/all_programs.html)

Seems pretty nice, now I actually have a decent understanding of how it works (yay!)

Comment: Huh, interesting. But it's not what you asked for.

Comment: @Brandon Sorry, I guess I asked to question wrong.  I wanted a good understanding of how Tix works, which is just an extension of Tkinter (I can now just use the documentation for Tix and apply it to what I learned about Tkinter, being very similar in overall structure)

Answer (score 0):

Re the roles of Tix and ttk. They are different things. Tix adds widgets to the standard Tkinter set. ttk adds widgets that duplicate existing widgets but with a configurable look 'n feel. So if you want to make your GUI look like the native OS apps use ttk, but you only get a limited set of widgets. If you want more powerful widgets and don't care about the look as much, then use Tix.